# Centering a div's/image's (off-centered) safe zone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a website which is composed of a big image, which I want to be as big as possible (occupying up to 100% of the screen) and a few paragraphs underneath.

```
 --------
|        |
|   IMG  |
|        | 
 ---------
|        | 
|        | 
|  TEXT  | 
|        | 
|        | 
 ---------
```

I'd like to define an (off-center) "safe zone" for the picture, so that that safe part of the picture is always completely visible.

The orange is the safe zone which should always be visible. It starts 11% from the left side and ends at the 35% mark (i.e. 24% of the image's width). Vertically, it starts 25% from the top and goes all the way to the bottom.

[image]

The following picture is a screenshot of a

The HTML is quite simple and currently includes only the image

```
<body>
    <div id="image">
        <h1>Matthew Perry</h1>
        <h2>Developer - Engineer - Mathematician</h2>

    </div>
</body>
```

While the CSS looks like this

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%; 
} 

#image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("matthew.JPG");

    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-x: 11%;
}
```

This produces a very good result for a laptop, using the "standard" 2/3 of the screen's width.
[image]

In an iPhone (and other mobile devices) it also acceptable
[image]

However, if I use the laptop's full screen, I loose part of the bottom and I don't want to imagine what would happen if a person visits the website using an ultra wide monitor.
[image]

How can I be sure that the safe zone is always visible? Any tips/recomendations on how to make this look good? Thanks!!

Comment: Alternatively, you mind find [responsive images](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images) useful in achieving [art direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#art_direction); see the [picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Comment: You may need to resort to a bit of Javascript, is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Put your entire page in a container with a max-width. Center it, and put black all around on the sides.

I know that you want to fill up the entire screen, but I would say that it's impossible, given all kinds of different resolutions. I mean, you shouldn't even use that kind of hi-res image on phones, because that eats up their RAM.

Another solution is to have different backgrounds based on different resolutions (mobile, desktop, ultrawide), and the use media-queries to display the different backgrounds. That would be friendlier to the smart phones as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way of doing this by pure CSS as you can't access the aspect ratio (100vw/100vh) AFAIK and media break points aren't general enough.

This snippet does it using JS. It uses a before pseudo element to hold the actual background image as that can then be scaled to fit as required without altering the main image div. If Matthew can't fit in when the image width is 100% then adjustments are made, see comments in among the code.

The only devices on the Chrome emulator which have to show some gray background left and right because there just isn't enough of the image to cover and have the safe zone in full view were landscaped Galaxy fold and iPad Pro. Nothing can be done about that (unless you have a wider aspect ratio image which could be used).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;    
} 

#image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
#image::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7mBJ.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position-y: bottom; /* with this image we always want it fixed to the bottom */
    background-size: var(--size);
    background-position-x: var(--x);
    transform-origin: var(--origin) bottom;
    transform: var(--scale);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image">
        <h1>Matthew Perry</h1>
        <h2>Developer - Engineer - Mathematician</h2>
    </div>
<script>
const imgW = 1630;
const imgH = 1080;
const safeL = 11;
const safeR = 35;
const safeT = 25;

const image = document.querySelector ('#image');

function resize() {
  const innerW = window.innerWidth;
  const innerH = window.innerHeight;
  
  image.style.setProperty('--origin', (safeL+(safeR - safeL)/2)*innerW/100 + 'px');
  image.style.setProperty('--scale', 'scale(1)');
   
  let scale = 1;
  
  // see whether Matthew fits in if we give the image the full width
  if (((100-safeT)/100*(1080/1630)*innerW) <= innerH) {
    // Matthew fits vertically
    image.style.setProperty('--size', '100vw auto');
    image.style.setProperty('--x', '0');
    // is image filling the container vertically?
    if ((1080/1630 * innerW) < innerH) {
      // Matthew fits vertically but the image isn't tall enough to cover the height so expand height to be innerH
      image.style.setProperty('size', 'auto ' + innerH + 'px');
      image.style.setProperty('--x', '0');
      // scale the background so Matthew has full height, and scale from middle of bottom of safe zone
      scale = innerH/(1080/1630 * innerW);
      image.style.setProperty('--scale', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
      image.style.setProperty('--x', '0'); // this needs refining for the fully general case
    }
  }
  else {
    // Matthew has his head chopped off at full width so make him full height
    const height = innerH*100/(100 - safeT);
    image.style.setProperty('--size', 'auto ' + height +'px');
    image.style.setProperty('--x', (innerW - (height*imgW/imgH))/2 + 'px');
  }  
}
window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```